# How does getArgs work?

Tags: haskell, io, arguments

I am trying to understand `getArgs` in Haskell. Here is what I have:

```
import System.Environment

myFunFunction = do
     args <- getArgs
     return $ head args
```

What I am getting when I run the function is

```
 *Main> myFunFunction
 *** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Does this not work the same way as `getLine`?  Why does it not ask for a command line argument?

Comment: args are supplied to the command line when invoking the program e.g. `prog arg1 arg2 ...`

Comment: You don't provide any argument to the program.

Comment: As in if I do myFunFunction "hello" It should work? @freestyle

Comment: @JamalCrawford, from doc: "Computation `getArgs` returns a list of the program's command line arguments (not including the program name)."

Comment: I can read a doc.  I am clearly having a disconnect.  Thats why I am asking on here

Comment: Use `withArgs ["test"] myFunFunction`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `getArgs` is `IO [String]`. When you bind it with `<-`, as in the OP, the bound symbol (`args`) gets the type `[String]`, i.e. a list of strings.

The `head` function returns the first element in a list; it has the type `[a] -> a`. It's (in)famous for being unsafe, in the sense that if you apply it to an empty list, it'll crash:

```
Prelude System.Environment> head []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

That's what's happening here. `getArgs` gives you the arguments you supplied at the command line when you ran the program. If you don't supply any arguments at the command line, then the returned list will be empty.

The `getArgs` function isn't interactive. It'll just return the arguments supplied from the command line, if any were supplied.

Comment: Also possibly of interest: when testing things in ghci, just running `main` won't set up the argument list in any special way, but `:main foo bar baz` will.