# Why is getArgs evaluated after fmap method argument?

Tags: haskell, io, functor

Why does `getArgs` gets evaluated after the method argument of `fmap`?

```
main::IO()
main=do
    fpath<-fmap head getArgs
    putStrLn fpath
```

I get the error :
`Exception: Prelude.head: empty list`
It seems it applies head on something that has not been computed yet.

I first assumed that it might be another rule about lazyness that i am not aware of being new to Haskell so i tried with :
`a<-fmap head getLine` # no problem
 
`a<-fmap head (readFile [filename])` # again no problem

So why is `getArgs` special that gets evaluated after ?

Comment: `getArgs` is not evaluated in any special way. It is just returning an empty list. Are you actually launching your program with some argument? Note, from the documentation, that the returned list does not include the program name but only the command-line arguments.

Comment: If you get an exception about the list returned by `getArgs` being empty, that's almost certainly because it *is* empty, not because of evaluation order. When `head` is applied to an argument that hasn't been evaluated, then the argument will be evaluated at that point - it won't just claim the argument is an empty list when it might not be. That's not how laziness works.

Comment: In Haskell, one does not evaluate arguments directly (not left-to-right, or at least not as a general rule). It is evaluated lazily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `head` breaks on empty list, that means that `getArgs` *did* already evaluate, because the value `[]` was produced and matched by `head`.

Most probably you ran your program from `ghci`, which can produce such an effect. Since `head` is unsafe, you should check whether there's at least one argument on the list present.

Comment: I did run it from `ghci` and i was expecting to be  prompted to enter the arguments

Comment: "Most probably you ran your program from ghci, which can produce such an effect." What do you mean by that?

Comment: @sepp2k That if you have a haskell program which you load into an interactive environment, and call `main` manually, it will receive no arguments (because, in fact, none were provided). You [can provide those arguments using `:main`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055999/how-does-getargs-work#comment85117310_49056302).